# Page Template PHP file not linking CSS file

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have the `php file` and in that I am linking a `HTML` file.

```
include 'practice.html';
```

In the HTML file I have a few CSS files linked.

```
    <link href="practice1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="practice2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Now, what is happening is the Page Template is displaying only the HTML part and not able to access the CSS files.

How can I possibly use CSS files?

PS : ALL my PHP, HTML, and CSS files are under the same folder `(wordpress\wp-content\themes\*)`.

Comment: You should use `wp_enqueue_style` to add your stylesheets: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

Comment: @jeroen I have my CSS files already linked to the HTML file, so do I need to link it again in the PHP file when I am already linking the HTML file?

Comment: You should try to follow WordPress's method of including files and assets in general to avoid running into problems later on.

Comment: @jeroen So where am I wrong? I am creating a php file and linking the HTML file (which has some css files in it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your PHP template page, use:

```
<?php require(TEMPLATEPATH.'\practice.html'); ?>
```

And on your HTML page, use:

```
<link href="\wordpress\wp-content\themes\YourThemeName\practice1.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="\wordpress\wp-content\themes\YourThemeName\practice2.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Make sure to replace YourThemeName with, your theme's name. And also to provide the correct path of where your CSS files are located.

If your wondering about what TEMPLATEPATH does, it provides the path to the template in use by WordPress so you do not have to type out the full path ex. \wordpress\wp-content\themes\YourThemeName\

Are you working on a local server or a live website? Depending on which one it is, you will have to change up the paths.

Example:

For a live website use:

```
/wordpress/wp-content/themes/YourThemeName/
```

or

For a local server use:

```
\wordpress\wp-content\themes\YourThemeName\
```

Comment: When I am including the above in the php template page it is giving error : ` Failed opening required 'C:\wamp\www\wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteenpracitce.html'`

Comment: I got it when I removed the "Templatepath" from `<?php require(TEMPLATEPATH.'practice.html'); ?>`

Comment: You should keep "TEMPLATEPATH". What was missing in the above code snippet was a forward slash "/".

ex.

    <?php require(TEMPLATEPATH.'/practice.html'); ?>

I've updated my code snippet to use a forward slash in the path.

Comment: Even then it gives error. See the ` \\` changes to `/` after wordpress directory, thus not giving the correct location.

Comment: But why do we use TEMPLATEPATH when it works fine even if we do not use it.

Comment: TEMPLATEPATH was useful so you would not have to type the full path to a file ex. /wordpress/wp-content/themes/YourThemeName/YourFileName.php Using TEMPLATEPATH you would simply call a file with the following: TEMPLATEPATH.'/YourFileName.php' Take a look at some useful functions similar to TEMPLATEPATH over at the WordPress Codex website: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory  Also make sure to mark your question answered!

Comment: But it works even if we don't use that. I mean we don't have to specify anything extra.

Comment: In programming, there is usually always more than one way to do something. I am not going to get technical on that but whether using the TEMPLATEPATH function, or others, or not, or simply providing the path manually, things will still work. Using the provided functions speeds up development that's all and remember WordPress is a Dynamic Based Content Management System Template Engine. Imagine having to change a bunch of paths manually? Just think that when using these functions it would be one less full path to write out!

Comment: Not getting the CSS when doing it for the live website in my control panel, Also there is no folder here name as wordpress, this is the addpress of my  html file `/home3/username/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme/practice.html`

Comment: Sure! Drop the following code snippet into your practice.html file within the head section. Remember to replace 'YourThemeName, with your theme's name.

<link href="/wp-content/themes/YourThemeName/practice1.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/wp-content/themes/YourThemeName/practice2.css" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 0):

try using [Include PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) for including HTML file and for the CSS you can simply use `echo`

```
<?php


echo '<link href="practice1.css" rel="stylesheet">';
include('practice.html');

?>
```

Comment: Does not  work. It is able to display the HTML file (but not the CSS files that are linked to the HTML file).

Comment: try ECHOing <link /> tag with full pathname ie 
`echo <link href="\wordpress\wp-content\themes\YourThemeName\practice1.css" rel="stylesheet">`